# Syncml Client for iPhone

Tags: iphone, syncml

I need Syncml client for iPhone which could be an opensource.
Any download Links accessible to Syncml client would be helpful for me..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Funambol client for iphone

http://funambol.com/solutions/iphone.php